# How to view code coverage details in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, test-coverage

When I run Code Coverage -either as part of invoking a unit test or from `Analyze | Generate Coverage Report` the result is only a one-line summary as shown:

[image]

Instead what we want is to see coverage ***by class*** - to hone in on the undertested areas.  Even better would be detailing per-class areas (to the lines?)   Does IJ have any of those capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!  It show up in the Explorer.  Now there really **should** also be a text report .. so if anyone knows where that is or how to generate it another answer would be appreciated.

NOte: I can not show the full path names for confidentiality reasons

[image]

Comment: There is a Generate Coverage Report button (box with green arrow pointing up) in the tool bar next to that table. Also if you double click on one of the classes there the coverage should be displayed in the editor that opens (geen/red bars in the gutter).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Intellij documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-code-coverage-report.html). To generate a code coverage report

1. Do one of the following:

   - On the main menu, choose Analyze | Generate Coverage Report.
   - In the toolbar of the Coverage tool window, click `exportToTextFile`.
2. In the Generate Coverage Report dialog box that opens, specify the target directory where the generated report will be stored, and optionally select the check box Open generated HTML in browser.
3. Click Save. IntelliJ IDEA will store the generated report to the specified location, and also open it in the default browser, if the corresponding check box has been selected.

Comment: Huh.. that directory does not exist. Any suggestions why that might be?

Comment: Ok. I sometimes run tests from the command line and that directory may have been generated by sbt. I came across this link that might be of use https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html

Comment: Apologies. What about this one? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-code-coverage-report.html